# how to retrieve token in localstorage to set in header in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a problem that I can't retrieve data directly from localstorage, so first I have the response data from the API then I set it to local storage, I want to retrieve the data that is in local storage, then I set it to the header in axios, how do I retrieve and organize it data into the header?

this is my function for generate token from app.js

```
const getAppToken = () => {
    Api.post('/auth/api/v1/generateToken', {auth:{username: 'john doe', password: '123123'}})
      .then(res => (res.data.data.token !== null && res.data.data.token !== "" && storageData('token', res.data.data.token)))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

this is axios interceptor

```
Api.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    const appToken = await getData('token')
    if (appToken) {
      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + appToken
    } else {
      console.log('error, token gk masuk')
    }
    return config
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
)
```

this is an example of a function for the get API that requires a header from home.js and another file

```
Api.get(`/master/api/v1/aboutUs/fetch`, {
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${getData('token')}` }
})
```

this is function get and set localstorage

```
export const storageData = (key, value) => {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

export const getData = (key) => {
    try {
        const value = localStorage.getItem(key)
        return (value !== null && value) 
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: why `await getData`? it's not asynchronous

Comment: if you want to use the result from `getAppToken` (which you don't seem to in your code) you'll need to actually return something from that function ... currently you don't, since you return what `storageData` returns, which is nothing

Comment: first using await without async, second did you check the value available in localstorage or not?

Comment: @JaromandaX So I save the results of the getToken in the state first or what? I am new to React Js

Comment: @JaromandaX the response from getToken has entered localstorage but how do I retrieve it for me to set in the header?

Comment: use `localStorage.getItem`

Comment: I have changed it to localStorage, but the header can't retrieve data from the localStorage, please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the data here, you are returning a boolean.

```
  return (value !== null && value)
```

Just do this instead

```
 return value
```

If the value doesn't exist it'll just return null

Comment: I have conditioned it as you mean, but this has not worked, how do I solve this case?

Comment: the response from getToken has entered localstorage but how do I retrieve it for me to set in the header?